# Adding images sequentially on DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

This snippet is from a Blackjack game where I wish to display new card images on DOM everytime a hit button is clicked.

```js
// ***************************************** //
function DeckObject() {

    this.cardArray = []
      // ***************************************** //
    this.displayCards = function(cardPair) {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
          var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
          imgElement.src = "Images/" + cardPair[i].cardNum + "_of_" + cards[i].cardSuit + ".png";
          fragment.appendChild(imgElement);
        }
        if (this === User) {
          showUserCards.appendChild(fragment); //showUserCards is a var with div element
        } else {
          showDealerCards.appendChild(fragment);
        }
      }
      // ***************************************** //
    this.hitCard = function(cardPair) {
      var extraCard = cardPair.push(MainDeck.cardArray.pop());
      this.displayCards(cardPair[extraCard - 1]); //display only the new added card
    }
  }
  // **************************************** //
```

**So what I'm basically doing is : on every 'hitButton' click, I execute hitCard() function where I push a new card to initially passed cardArray.

 Then I pass only the newly added card to displayCards() function to show it in DOM.**

**Note:** *displayCards() is initially coded to take 'n-sized' array except when I pass single card object to it via the hitCard() function*

Comment: I don't see any problem or question in this post. What's not working ?

Comment: @ValLeNain it was not adding card images to the DOM when i passed a single card, but would do so if I passed more than 1 card. Unsure of this rare behavior, i posted this snippet here but found the answer myself later :)

Answer (score 0):

New image was not added to the DOM because while doing       **this.displayCards(cardPair[extraCard - 1]);**, I am passing the newly pushed card to the displayCard() function as an object. But displayCards() functions accepts an array as parameter and iterates through it, so it can't read the object.